# Odd character echoed from UART - PIC16F

Tags: pic, uart

I am working with a PIC16F1829. I have a UART interface that mostly works correctly. My issue is that whenever I type a character into CoolTerm, I get an echo of that character back or some other character. You see in the screenshot when I type "m" I get an "m" echoed back along with my data. Other times it's an "l" or some other character and then my data.

[image: CoolTerm Screenshot]

My question is, what is causing the echo back? It's not from CoolTerm.

I've tried so far:
 - Turning off any transmit on the PIC side. I still see this echo
 - Using Python to transmit and receive data, I still see this type of echo
 - Tried replacing the PIC
 - Tried different baud rates

This code was generated by the MCC generator

```
void EUSART_Initialize(void)
{
    // Set the EUSART module to the options selected in the user interface.
```

```
// ABDOVF no_overflow; SCKP Non-Inverted; BRG16 16bit_generator; WUE disabled; ABDEN disabled; 
BAUDCON = 0x08;

// SPEN enabled; RX9 8-bit; CREN enabled; ADDEN disabled; SREN disabled; 
RCSTA = 0x90;

// TX9 8-bit; TX9D 0; SENDB sync_break_complete; TXEN enabled; SYNC asynchronous; BRGH hi_speed; CSRC slave; 
TXSTA = 0x24;


// Baud Rate = 115200; SPBRGL 34; 
SPBRGL = 0x22;

// Baud Rate = 115200; SPBRGH 0; 
SPBRGH = 0x00;
```

}

uint8_t EUSART_Read(void)
{

```
while(!PIR1bits.RCIF)
{
}

if(1 == RCSTAbits.FERR)
{
    char a = RCREG; //Read a byte to clear FERR
}
if(1 == RCSTAbits.OERR)
{
    // EUSART error - restart

    RCSTAbits.CREN = 0; 
    RCSTAbits.CREN = 1; 
}

return RCREG;
```

}

void EUSART_Write(uint8_t txData)
{
    while(0 == PIR1bits.TXIF)
    {
    }

```
TXREG = txData;    // Write the data byte to the USART.
```

}
/**
  End of File
*/
void write_uart_str(char *str)
{
    while (*str != '\0') 
    {
        EUSART_Write(*str);
        (char *) str++;
    }
}
char *read_uart_str()
{
    #define MAX_UART_SIZE 32
    int i=0;
    char ch;
    char str[MAX_UART_SIZE];

```
for(i=0;i<MAX_UART_SIZE;i++)
{
    str[i]='\0';
}

do
{
    ch = EUSART_Read();
    str[i]=ch;
    i++;
}while (ch != '\0');

return (char *)str;
```

}
char read_uart_ch()
{
    return EUSART_Read();
}

void main(void)
{
    // initialize the device
    SYSTEM_Initialize();

// When using interrupts, you need to set the Global and Peripheral Interrupt Enable bits
// Use the following macros to:

// Enable the Global Interrupts
INTERRUPT_GlobalInterruptEnable();

// Enable the Peripheral Interrupts
INTERRUPT_PeripheralInterruptEnable();

// Disable the Global Interrupts
//INTERRUPT_GlobalInterruptDisable();

// Disable the Peripheral Interrupts
//INTERRUPT_PeripheralInterruptDisable();


char ch=0;

write_uart_str((char*) ("\nRunning Version: "));
write_uart_str(VERSION);
write_uart_str("\n");
accelerometer_init();

write_uart_str("\nSelect Option\n");
write_uart_str(menu_options);

while (1) {
    // Add your application code
    ch=0;



    while(!ch)
        ch = read_uart_ch();
           //write_uart_str("Read: ");
           //write_uart_str(ch);
           //write_uart_str("\n");
    switch (ch) {
        case 'c':
        {
            accelerometer_calibrate();
            write_uart_str("Calibrated Accelerometer\n");
            break;
        }

        case 'i':
        {
            int id = accelerometer_get_deviceID(); //Should be 0xE5
            char str_buf[16];
            write_uart_str("Device ID: ");
            write_uart_str(itoa(str_buf, id, 10));
            write_uart_str("\n");
            break;
        }
        case 'x':
        {
            struct accel_xyz xyz = accelerometer_read();
            char str_buf[16];
            write_uart_str("\nX: ");
            write_uart_str(itoa(str_buf, xyz.x, 10));
            write_uart_str("\n");
            break;
        }
        case 'y':
        {
            struct accel_xyz xyz = accelerometer_read();
            char str_buf[16];
            write_uart_str("\nY: ");
            write_uart_str(itoa(str_buf, xyz.y, 10));
            write_uart_str("\n");
            break;
        }
        case 'z':
        {
            struct accel_xyz xyz = accelerometer_read();
            char str_buf[16];
            write_uart_str("\nZ: ");
            write_uart_str(itoa(str_buf, xyz.z, 10));
            write_uart_str("\n");
            break;
        }
        case 'm':
        {
            struct accel_xyz xyz = accelerometer_read();
            char str_buf[16];

            xyz=accelerometer_read();
            write_uart_str(itoa(str_buf, xyz.x, 10)); write_uart_str(" ");
            write_uart_str(itoa(str_buf, xyz.y, 10)); write_uart_str(" ");
            write_uart_str(itoa(str_buf, xyz.z, 10));
            write_uart_str("\n");

            break;
        }
        case 'r':
        {
            struct accel_xyz xyz = accelerometer_read();
            char str_buf[16];
            write_uart_str("\nPress p to pause\n");
            write_uart_str("X       Y       Z\n");
            do {
                xyz=accelerometer_read();
                write_uart_str(itoa(str_buf, xyz.x, 10)); write_uart_str(" ");
                write_uart_str(itoa(str_buf, xyz.y, 10)); write_uart_str(" ");
                write_uart_str(itoa(str_buf, xyz.z, 10));
                write_uart_str("\n");
            }while (1); //read_uart_ch() != 'p'
            break;
        }

    }

}

}

I am using this RS232 Level translation module for the driver: It's connected to TX/RX pins on the PIC.
https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/seeed-technology-co-ltd/101990008/1597-1306-ND/5487765

Comment: How do you know it's not from CoolTerm? Can you see the local echo setting off? And how can you "turn off any transmit" if you are transmitting data?

Comment: I suggest trying another terminal emulator, also include the code in the pic.

Comment: also, l an m have codes near the carriage return, maybe it has something to do with that

Comment: Looks like maybe some crosstalk at the hardware level. Can you show us your PIC's RS232 driver circuit and how you have it connected to the PC?

Comment: @Eugene  Sh- It's not CoolTerm because the Echo setting is off. I also have a Python script that I wrote and it sees the same characters.

Comment: Then you will have to show us your code

Comment: Did you test for a physical short circuit between your tx and rx lines? Your program would likely not mind, but all input would be seen on the tx side too.

Answer (score -2):

I think I have found the problem.

When you get wrong characters being sent back, it tends to be a mismatch in bitrate:

- Your PIC code uses // Baud Rate = 115200; SPBRGL 34;
- CoolTerm is also using 115200

However looking at the datasheet of the TTL level driver, it states:

• Operates up to 250 kbit/s

If you go back in to your code for the PIC (and CoolTerm), change the bitrate of the UART to 250 kbit/s, it should solve the problem.

Also would suggest to hook it up to an oscilloscope to see exactly what you are getting using a single shot trigger.

Comment: I tried lowering the baud rate to 300 and I still have the same issue. Though now I consistently get back the same character I typed in. I know it's not CoolTerm's echo feature because I can enable that and then the character will show up twice.